# Windows Mobile 10 Bluetooth LE Connect/Disconnect without pairing

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, gatt

I'm developing an app on the Windows Mobile 10 preview.

I have a Bluetooth product that I need to connect to, write some values then disconnect. I currently do this just fine in Android and iOS.

It seems that Windows Mobile 10 requires the device to be paired manually by the user and then it will automatically connect to the device. I really don't want this behaviour because it's important that other devices be able to connect.

Let me give the example of a door lock using Bluetooth LE. In this case there will be many phones that need to lock/unlock the door. It makes no sense to pair the door lock to one phone because that would automatically connect to the device (and thus prevent any other phone from connecting).

What's the solution in Windows Mobile 10 for our door lock? Can we pair/unpair from code?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with the same issue, did you find any solution?